# Generics - Create data on the fly

Tags: java, generics, reflection, types

This is a complicated question which i will find hard to explain so i appologise in advance.

Imagine an application that invokes another projects methods. I need a way of generating data to match the parameter list. Obviously if the parameter types are of some class that I have no way of generating then it should fail but if its an `int[]` and `int[][]` a `List<String>` a `Map<Integer, String>` then it should be possible.

What i am struggling with is a decent approach for solving this. I can  get the types of parameters via `method.getGenericParameterTypes();` example for the parameter HashMap would be `java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer>` but there are quite a lot of different possibilities right!

I assume generics has some use here? The only issue with that being I have no control over the code that is being invoked. How can I use one of these types and then generate data for it?

I am sorry for the poor explanation, any help appreciated

Thanks

Here we see an example of a method i want to invoke, I want to record how long it takes to run (this is being done via reflection) however, i need to generate data for the parameters. I need a way of generating data to match

```
public void someMethod(Param a, Param b, Param c)
{
    //some user code I have no control over
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the problem?

Comment: Have you considered using Dynamic Proxies?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html

Comment: Sounds like you've split your problem into two, solved the easy part and are now struggling with the impossible one. Explain **why** you want to do this and your real problem and I'm pretty sure there'll be a better solution.

Comment: @Voo its a project to record the run time complexity of a users algorithm. I need to measure how long it takes to run and work out the onotation. in order to do so i need to generate data of different lengths and measure the run time

Comment: In that case I'd force the user to write the looping code. You really can't create valid input arguments out of thin air for arbitrary classes. What if my function takes a `Foo` object that does not accept a default constructor? Now you have to guess what to pass into one of the constructors most certainly violating all possible preconditions while doing so. You can take a look at google's [Caliper project](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/) that solves a pretty similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps the question should be *why* you need to do this.  Perhaps if you explained your use/business case, we can provide a cleaner (and easier) solution.

From your very last lines, you are talking about wanting to profile the method.  Generally speaking, it is rare to want to profile just one small tiny method in the middle of chain of processing.  That being said, I can imagine some convoluted cases where this might occur.  However, even at that, it should be a handful of cases that you would be able to code yourself.

If it is a question of actual profiling, but you are not sure how to do it, and consequently feel that the only way is to call each method individually so you can "wrap" it with a start/stop timer, I would strongly recommend looking into [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).  Both [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) and [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) are great for AOP, with AspectJ able to do byte-weaving that Spring is unable to accomplish.

Consequently, with AspectJ you would be able to create your own profiling timer classes and weave them into the byte-code at compile time and then run your standard tests, but visualize all the profiling info that you want/need on a per-method basis.

And best of all, it would avoid you needing to come up with some convoluted scheme for producing random test data that isn't really relevant to the method being tested.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a horrible problem.

If you have the class[] that represents the parameter types of the method then can't you create a new instance of each and pass that as the arguments list to the method? This is untested:

```
Class[] parameterTypes = method.getGenericParameterTypes();

Object[] args = new Object[parameterTypes.length];

for (int i=0; i < parameterTypes.length; i++) {
    args[i] = parameterTypes[i].newInstance(); // assuming the classes can be instantiated without params
}    

method.invoke(obj, args); // I assume you've instantiated the object already
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your approach most definatley would work in a lot of instances I believe? But the issue i see is that they would all be empty data sets? Thanks again.

Comment: Its very possible i have misunderstood your code :$ Your taking the parameter list and creating an instance of each one?

Comment: That's it. The parameters list is an array of `Class` objects. If you call `newInstance()` on a Class object then it creates an Object from it.

Comment: so if it was a parameter of ArrayList<String> it would create a new instance of that correct? My point is that the collection will be empty. Please don't think i am being argumentative, its just my main aim is to get a set of parameters with values in or at least some way of knowing what to populate them with.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is that you could check to see if the class extends collection using `class.isAssignableFrom(Collections.Class)`. You can then populate it if you need to. But that would mean that you'd have to check each parameter Class.

Comment: would it have the parameterised type? and what if it were a primitive type like int[][]?